# Issue calling my functions on Plugin activate in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

I am Creating New Wordpress Plugin and splitting my code into different files for code management. 
Here is code of my main Plugin file which `my-best-plugin.php`with following code:

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ){
        die;
    }

    if(!defined('MY_PLUGIN_PATH')) { 
        define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) ); 
    }

    if( ! class_exists('MyBestPlugin') ){
        class MyBestPlugin {

            function mbp_activate(){
                require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH .'inc/mbp-plugin-activate.php';
                MBPActivate::activate();
            }

        }

        $pluginInstance = new MyBestPlugin();

        // activation
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , array( $pluginInstance, 'mbp_activate' ) );

    }
```

Now in my second file which is for activation is located in `inc/mbp-plugin-activate.php` and code is below:

```
<?php

    class MBPActivate {

        public static function activate(){
            // I want to do more here by calling functions
            // cpt(); 
            // dont know how to call function cpt()
            // also not sure is it running properly or not :P
            add_action('init', array( 'MBPActivate','cpt' ));
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        public static function cpt(){
            register_post_type('book', ['public'=>true, 'label'=>'Books']);
        }

    }
```

first Im not sure my plugin activate file is running or not but giving No error, also when I call my own functions it gives fatal error OR headers already sent error.
Please tell me how to call my functions during activation from activate plugin file.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're going to need to give a specific example of something that's not working. As far as I can tell, what's in this question is fine.

Comment: now look at the code of activate file. this is how Im declaring new Custom Post Type which is not showing in menu.

Comment: Custom post types aren't registered on activation. They're supposed to be registered on the `init` hook. Only functions that write to the database or files are typically run on activation. Most functions run on a hook of some kind.

Comment: Yes Im getting your point, but can you please tell me how to call some other custom function on activate? like I can create table in DB via that function etc

Comment: Just run the function inside the activate function. There's nothing more to it. You're doing the right thing to run functions on activation, you're just using the wrong functions.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help! Im adding new Custom Post Type and enqueue some admin side Scripts but Im not successful in this way...

Comment: Neither of those things have anything to do with plugin activation, that's why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95418/discussion-between-faisal-janjua-and-jacob-peattie).

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:-

```
   // Make sure we don't expose any info if called directly
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ){
    die;
}

if(!defined('MY_PLUGIN_PATH')) { 
    define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) ); 
}

if( ! class_exists('MyBestPlugin') ){
        class MyBestPlugin {

            public function __construct(){
                register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , array( $this, 'mbp_activate' ) );
                register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , array( $this, 'mbp_deactivate' ) );
                if(get_option('cpt_enable')){
                   add_action( 'init', array($this, 'cpt' ) ); 
                } //get the 'cpt enabled option if available.Hit the hook'
            }

            public function mbp_activate(){
                require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH .'inc/yes.php';
                MBPActivate::activate();
            }

            public function mbp_deactivate(){
                require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH .'inc/yes.php';
                MBPActivate::deactivate();
            }

            public function cpt(){
                $args = array(
                                'public'    => true,
                                'label'     => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
                                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
                            );
                register_post_type( 'book', $args );
            }

        }

        $pluginInstance = new MyBestPlugin();

}
```

//////next page yes.php////

```
class MBPActivate {
        public function activate(){
            add_option('cpt_enable','cpt_enable'); // set the cpt enabled option after activation hook.
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
        public function deactivate(){
            delete_option('cpt_enable');
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
    }
    $plugin = new MBPActivate();
```

Comment: how can I run my custom functions on activating plugin?

Comment: Updated and checked. it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

**my-plugin.php file**

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Plugin URI: http://#####
Description: This plugin just for test
Author: Chetan Vaghela
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://che##la.###/
*/
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ){
        die;
}
if(!defined('MY_PLUGIN_PATH')) { 
    define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) ); 
}

function mbp_activate(){
  flush_rewrite_rules();
  add_option( 'my_plugin_activated', time() );
}
require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH .'inc/mbp-plugin-activate.php';
function run_mbpactive() {

    $plugin = new MBPActivate();

}
run_mbpactive();

register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'mbp_activate'  );


register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_uninstall' );
function my_plugin_uninstall() {
     unregister_post_type( 'book' );
     delete_option("my_plugin_activated");
}
```

**inc/mbp-plugin-active.php file**

```
<?php
class MBPActivate {

     public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'init', array($this, 'cptcallback' ) );

    }

    public function cptcallback(){

       // / die("calledddd");
        $books_labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'Books name', 'text-domain' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'Books name', 'text-domain' ),
            'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'text-domain' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Books', 'add new on admin bar', 'text-domain' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'text-domain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'text-domain' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No Books found.', 'text-domain' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Books found in Trash.', 'text-domain' )
        );

        $books_args = array(
            'labels'             => $books_labels,
            'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'text-domain' ),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-testimonial'
        );
        register_post_type( 'book', $books_args );

    }
}
```

let me know if it is works for you!